# Eliminar el indice de un array de un Componente Padre desde un Componente hijo en Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy aprendiendo reactjs, y mi pregunta es como puedo eliminar un array del componente padre desde el componente hijo, cree dos componentes uno formulario y otro que se llama table, el formulario me permite capturar los datos en el componente padre, y en el table los imprimo, pero estoy creando las acciones de eliminar, modificar... y mi pregunta es esa, Cuando lo realizo al subir un dato me lo elimina , es obvio por la funcion, pero como hago para eliminar, y disculpa la molestia. aqui mi codigo, Empiezo desde el componente padre que es App:

```
 class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [],
      nombre:'',
      apellido: '',
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleDestroy = this.handleDestroy.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
    this.state.list.push({nombre:this.state.nombre,apellido:this.state.apellido})
    this.setState({
      nombre:'',
      apellido:''
    })
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  handleDestroy(value){

    this.state.list.splice(value, 1)

 }

  render(){
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Formulario 
              nombre={this.state.nombre} 
              apellido={this.state.apellido} 
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
              handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              />
            <Table listado={this.state.list} clickDestroy={this.handleDestroy()}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

    class Table extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Apellido</th>
                        <th>Acción</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                         this.props.listado.map((lista,index) =>{
                            return( 

                                    <tr key={index.toString()}>
                                        <td>{index}</td>
                                        <td>{lista.nombre}</td>
                                        <td>{lista.apellido}</td>
                                        <td><button onClick = {this.props.clickDestroy}>Eliminar</button></td>
                                    </tr>

                             );
                         })
                    }

                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }

}

class Formulario extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <form >
                <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value={this.props.nombre} onChange={this.props.handleChange}/>
                <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" value={this.props.apellido} onChange={this.props.handleChange}/>
                <button type="submit" onClick={this.props.handleSubmit}>Enviar</button>
            </form>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: `<td><button onClick = {() => this.props.clickDestroy(index)}>Eliminar</button></td>`
en primera necesitas pasarle el index del row que quieres eliminar, y ya en clickDestroy puedes hacerlo con el splice, como lo tienes, o con filter, para que te quite el elemento con la posicion que se manda

Comment: Gracias :), me funciono e.e un millon :) tenga un buen dia bro